# Mathematica: Extract elements of an array of lists

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica

I need to extract elements of an array of lists.
The array of lists comes from ImageData[.., "Byte"], like in the example below.

```
i = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
array=ImageData[ImageTake[i, {1, 5}, {1, 5}], "Byte"];
MatrixForm@array
```

positions is a list, where every element determines the element of the array, which has to be extracted:

```
positions = {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}
```

The result has to be an array of lists again. In this example containing two elements, the one which is specified by {2,3} and the one which is specified by {4,5}.

Unfortunately Mathematica's Extract-Function does not work with arrays containing lists. 
Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: The problem desription is a bit unclear.  How does what you want differ from `Extract[array, positions]`?

Comment: you might use `ImageValue`, but extract should work as well. I assume you know for your color image each pixel is a length 3 list.

Comment: What do you mean `Extract` doesn't work with lists of lists? It does. Can you post your attempt so we can understand?

Comment: I figured out the solution. Sometimes you have just to sleep an night over it. The curly brackets lead to the output i wanted:
    MatrixForm[{Extract[array, positions]}]
Without those curly brackets, the output is not in the same format, as the input. I dont know why, but it works :-)